# Javascript Onload Prompt where yes redirects to page

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to create a JS prompt box, where yes or ok redirects you to a site and no does nothing, and if so, could this appear on page load?

Thanks!

EDIT: Answer below. Seems easier than i thought! Thanks 'captain'!

Comment: Yes, and welcome to SO. What have you tried? Post what you have so far.

Comment: Ive used this: <script type="text/javascript">
function alertUser(msg) {
alert(msg);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="alertUser('Welcome to this AMAZING web page!')">

Comment: but, i want it to redirect to a page when a confirmation is recieved.

Comment: Check code I pasted :)

Comment: Answer below by user: captain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show `confirmation box` on `onload event`

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <!-- put html code here -->
</body>

function myFunction() {
   var redirect = confirm("Redirect to http://www.xyz.com ?");
   if (redirect == true) {
       window.location.href = 'http://www.xyz.com'; //redirect to http://www.xyz.com.
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay, will try. Thanks! Actually, looking at it, this makes more sense as it follows the "myFunction()" variable.

Comment: THANK YOU KIND SIR! This works perfectly (after some minor tweaking)

Comment: Answer voted as this, although i must have more reputation to vote it up. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one reason for doing so is that the else clause has no purpose.

Comment: @Jeffman I know else has nothing to do but as per function definition `every function must return a value`. Down-voters could have spend a thought on this

Comment: Edited for all those who dont like function definition .

Answer (score 0):

You may use `confirm` to do so. But instead of Yes/No, it displays Ok/Cancel.

[MDN Documentation on `window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.confirm)

Comment: Thats okay. At least its a working prompt. 

Could you post how you implant that please?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(){
var r=confirm("Press a button");
if (r==true)
  {
  alert("you pressed ok do your navigation here")
  }
else
  {
  alert("you pressed cancel do nothing here")
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="check()">
</body>
</html>
```

Heres your entire test code.

Comment: Thank You!! Testing it now, if its functional and working, i will vote this as the answer.